# Laravel selecting data with multiple where clauses and returning any pivot data

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship in my app where a organisation can have many users and many users can have many organisations, in my model this looks like this,

Organisation.php

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('is_admin');
}
```

User.php

```
public function organisations() {
        $this->belongsToMany('Organisation');
}
```

What I am wanting to do, is run a query that has multiple where clauses and then return the row data and any pivot data.

For one where clause I would do the following,

`$org = Organisation::find(1);`
`$orgUsers = $org->users()`;

What I cannot figure out is how I would user multiple wheres if I needed too?

Comment: I don't really get what you want here. And your code isn't even valid (you forgot to `return` `$this->belongsToMany('Organisation')` and to `$org->users()->get()` or `$org->users`. Do you want to apply multiple where clauses to the organization, and then get its users? Or do you want its users, but applying other where clauses to it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add the `wheree()`'s to users, it might look something like this (Eager loading the users)

```
$constraints = ['fname' => 'john', 'lanme' => 'doe'];

$org = Organisation::with(['users' => function($query) use ($constraints){

    foreach($constraints as $field => $val)
        $query->where($field, $val);

    // Or if you just want admin users using your pivot table field
    $query->pivot->where('is_admin', true);

}])->find($id);
```

Or, you could get them all, and filter them if you need a collection of users, and a collection of admins

```
$org = Organisation::with('users')->find($id);

$admins = $org->users->filter(function($user){ return $user->pivot->is_admin });
```